# Angular.js nested Controller $scopes must be predefined?

Tags: angularjs

## Why is defining a property for the child controller's $scope properties necessary?

### This ng-class on the HTML element works:

```
app.controller("mainController",['$anchorScroll','$scope','$location',function($anchorScroll,$scope,$location){
$scope.forms={};
}]);

app.controller("modalController",['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.forms.contactForm = false;
  $scope.forms.toggleContactForm = function(){
        $scope.forms.contactForm = !$scope.forms.contactForm;
  }
}]);

<body ng-controller="mainController">
   <div ng-class="{hidden:!forms.contactForm}" id="contactForm" ng-controller="modalController"></div>
</body>
```

### This ng-class does not:

```
app.controller("mainController",['$anchorScroll','$scope','$location',function($anchorScroll,$scope,$location){
}]);

app.controller("modalController",['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.contactForm = false;
  $scope.toggleContactForm = function(){
        $scope.contactForm = !$scope.contactForm;
  }
}]);

<body ng-controller="mainController">
    <div ng-class="{hidden:!contactForm}" id="contactForm" ng-controller="modalController"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you're running into something similar to what is described here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/943

Answer (score 4):

Because in the first case, you access `$scope.forms` via reference value (both controllers point to the same value in memory), and in the second case you just create a boolean primitive in the child controller, in which case the parent is completely unaware of it (and vice versa).

Comment: Thx!  In my case I was using the same child controller in several places in the DOM so each one was making it's own instance.  Still figuring out the Angular way.